# How did they manage to rebuild King's Landing so quickly after it was burned down by the dragon?

Tags: game-of-thrones

This question refers to the TV series "Game of Thrones" final season, so be careful, there are spoilers ahead!

In the final season, Daenerys Targaryen burns the entire city of King's Landing, including the Red Keep, to ashes. In the epilogue, after Bran Stark is chosen as the king, the Red Keep and the entire city are presented as completely perfect, including the castle, buildings, gardens, and trees.

How was the city rebuilt so fast after it was burned down?

Comment: It is amazing what can be accomplished with a dream, and an endless supply of expendable labor!

Comment: I'm not sure there is an in-universe explanation for the out-of-universe question "Why was King's Landing *depicted* as not having been destroyed?"

Comment: Perhaps because D&D "kinda forgot" about how destroyed King's Landing was. With all the stupidity of season 8, looking for logical in-universe explanations seems futile. The most likely reason is that no one out-universe though of it, or saw it as a problem. Which is sad.